# android studio 3.0.1 taking forever to fetch results of memory allocation in android profiler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

I'm trying to profile my app's memory allocations but android studio is taking very long time to fetch results of allocation recording (in fact it's been 45 min and ITS STILL FETCHING !!!)

here's a screenshot
[image]
JUST LOOK AT THE TIME

Comment: Try restarting it

Comment: I did .. like 3 times

Comment: you are only running one instance of Android Studio and you don't have Eclipse or ADB running at the same time in a separate window?

Comment: Yup , only android studio

Comment: Well I guess I've to brainstorm every part of my app until I find the bugs .. I hate old fashioned ways

Comment: The Android Profiler has performance issues. While [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68850784) may not be what you are experiencing, some of the suggestions in the comments might help.

Comment: It seems like this is still an issue with Profiler in 2019...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Android Studio 3.2.1 and Samsung S5 on Android 6. I just used another device on Android 8 and allocations became visible. So, I guess, it depends on device or Android version.

Comment: How do we know which device to use?

Comment: Same problem here with AS 3.4 and a SGS5 too I'm using for testing. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

My profiler was stuck on "fetching" because the debugger was also started and it paused my app because it reached a breakpoint

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons that it could take a long time could be your method count been very huge, that by itself could be a memory issue if you got too many chained things in your code.

For example, you got class `A` sending some data to class `B`, let's say a username, and then class `B` sends it to class `C` et cetera... until it gets to class `Z`

You can break the chain by using a **Singleton** and make `Z` and any other class to pull the username data directly from the source.

To determinate if this indeed is your problem, try running the tool on a new test project with few lines of code.